# How to set Where condition in my model definition in laravel

Tags: laravel

MY model works perfectly:

```
class Customer extends Model
{


    /**
     * @var string The database table used by the model.
     */
    public $table = 'users';

    /**
     * @var array Validation rules
     */
    public $rules = [
    ];
    public $hasMany  = [
        'voucher' => ['ItScholarBd\Api\Models\Voucher']
    ];

}
```

This `Customer` model refers to `users` table. all users having `role_id=5` is only customers. So this Model will always fetch users data where `role_id = 5`. I can achieve this as usual practice. But is there any smart way to set this where clause inside this Model so that `Customer` model always fetch user data having `role_id = 5`. i.e: Customer::get(); will return `users` where `role_id = 5`

Comment: is this what you are looking for? https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#global-scopes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add following method in your customer model.

```
public function scopeCustomers($query)
{
    return $query->where('role_id', 5);
}
```

and fetch records like this:-

```
$customers = Customer::customers();
```